What is needed to power a OSRAM DULUX S 11W/827
If I want to light an OSRAM DULUX S 11W/827 lamp, what I need?
I found some information here:
Nominal voltage: 91V
Nominal current: 0.16A

but since it is a fluorescent lamp do I need a transformer/ballast, don't I?
Is there a single item I can connect in order to light it?

What power source do you intend to use? (A fine lamp - 40 years ago: why use it today?)

You need the ballast.
The luminaries where you are intended to put those lights have one.
You could buy a light fixture with the ballast and then repurpose it.
These days many people remove the ballasts as LED lamps don't need it.

You need a ballast. They come pre-made, which I recommend you to get.
If you are in a pinch and need to wind your own, you need a coil with and impedance of (assuming 230 V mains here):
(230-91)/0.16 = 869 Ω which at 50 Hz would be:
869/(2*Pi*50) = 2.77 H
EDIT: Forgot the phasors. Sorry about that. You need about 4.9 H inductance.
This assumes your fluorescent tube has an integral starter, or it won’t start.

(The variant without starter was DULUX S/E.)

@greybeard Sorry. A correction factor of approx 0.6 for the phasors? I’m mobile or I would have simulated it.

@greybeard Yes, the voltage waveform across it is not sinusodial, but close enough if OP is going to wind his own. It gets particularly nasty with recombination in the tube and at resonant frequency, but at 50 Hz and only caring about the macroscopic waveshape, close enough. Here is a nice article: https://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/9782/1/Tozer_physically.pdf
